# REGEXP_SUBSTR find groups

Tags: sql, regex, oracle, oracle10g

I'm not able to find the groups of my pattern, and it is really giving me a hard time.

I've went through many SO answers, and Oracle documentation also, but it seems regular expressions is my weak point.

Basically, what I want is to get the text between `$E[ ]#` and `$D[ ]#`
I've wrote the pattern `^(\$E\[([A-Z|a-z|0-9|_]+)\]#)((\$D\[(.)*\]#)?)$` which validates the entire string successfully, but I'm not able to find the groups in that pattern

I've tried to following query:

```
  SELECT 
        REGEXP_SUBSTR('$E[some_key]#$D[some value]#',pattern, 1) AS MATCH1, 
        REGEXP_SUBSTR('$E[some_key]#$D[some value]#',pattern, 2) AS MATCH2
  FROM DUAL;
```

I've tried many variations of the 4th parameter of the function `REGEXP_SUBSTR('some text','pattern above', 1)` and its getting me the complete string, also tried `REGEXP_SUBSTR('some text','pattern above', 1, 1)`, but got the same results, either the *full string* or *NULL*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Modified pattern:

```
^(\$E\[([A-Z|a-z|0-9|_]+)\]#)(\$D\[(.*)\]#)?$
```

Use [REGEXP_REPLACE with back reference](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B12037_01/server.101/b10759/functions115.htm) (works on Oracle 10g):

```
SELECT 
  REGEXP_REPLACE('$E[some_key]#$D[some value]#',pattern, '\2') AS MATCH1, 
  REGEXP_REPLACE('$E[some_key]#$D[some value]#',pattern, '\4') AS MATCH2
FROM DUAL;
```

On Oracle 11g you can do:

```
SELECT 
  REGEXP_SUBSTR('$E[some_key]#$D[some value]#',pattern, 1,1,null,2) AS MATCH1, 
  REGEXP_SUBSTR('$E[some_key]#$D[some value]#',pattern, 1,1,null,4) AS MATCH2
FROM DUAL;
```

Documentation: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/functions138.htm

Answer (score 1):

Try this pattern (only 11g):

```
\$(D|E)\[([^]]*)
```

with this query:

```
SELECT 
    REGEXP_SUBSTR('$E[some_key]#$D[some value]#',pattern, 1, 1, null, 2) AS MATCH1, 
    REGEXP_SUBSTR('$E[some_key]#$D[some value]#',pattern, 1, 2, null, 2) AS MATCH2
FROM DUAL;
```

This will get you the "first occurrence of the second sub expression" and the "second occurrence of the second sub expression" where "second sub expression" refers to what matches the second set of parentheses in the pattern.

Comment: My friend, REGEXP_SUBSTR takes either two or four parameters, see [oracle documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B12037_01/server.101/b10759/functions116.htm), also, I've tried the pattern you supplied, it matches **$E[ the first character** or **$D[ the first character**

Comment: According to [this oracle documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/functions138.htm) it takes six arguments - at least for release 11g. What version do you run?

Comment: Ok - so I guess you run 10g - I will try to find another solution for you.

Comment: Will your actual source string contain other information that needs to be ignored - apart from $E[] and $D[]?

Comment: No, just a string that looks like this `$E[someText]#$D[some value]#` and the $D[...]# part is optional, I don't also mind using another pattern to match only the desired parts of my input string via `REGEXP_REPLACE`, but I'm facing the same issue